# Rotation isn't running smoothly

Tags: c, rotation, sdl

I have a function that is meant to take a give angle and rotate the coordinates of a triangle by that angle. However, it pauses slightly then jumps to a new position rather than running smoothly.

The function works by translating the original coordinates to the origin, rotating them by the angle that has already been moved plus the specified angle. Then it translates the coordinates back to the unmodified positions before translating them to where the image currenty is.

```
void rotateTriangle(double angle_){
int ang = angle_ + angle;
triCoords[0]=((triCoords_[0] - triPos_[0])*cos(ang) - (triCoords_[1] - triPos_[1])*sin(ang)) + triPos_[0] + triPos[0];
triCoords[1]=((triCoords_[1] - triPos_[1])*cos(ang) + (triCoords_[0] - triPos_[0])*sin(ang)) + triPos_[1] + triPos[1];
triCoords[2]=((triCoords_[2] - triPos_[0])*cos(ang) - (triCoords_[3] - triPos_[1])*sin(ang)) + triPos_[0] + triPos[0];
triCoords[3]=((triCoords_[3] - triPos_[1])*cos(ang) + (triCoords_[2] - triPos_[0])*sin(ang)) + triPos_[1] + triPos[1];
triCoords[4]=((triCoords_[4] - triPos_[0])*cos(ang) - (triCoords_[5] - triPos_[1])*sin(ang)) + triPos_[0] + triPos[0];
triCoords[5]=((triCoords_[5] - triPos_[1])*cos(ang) + (triCoords_[4] - triPos_[0])*sin(ang)) + triPos_[1] + triPos[1];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, this:

```
int ang = angle_ + angle;
```

will of course truncate the floating-point angle to an integer. Since `sin()` and `cos()` work with radians, that doesn't work out too well.

You should have:

```
const double ang = angle_ + angle;
```

It's not clear what `angle` is here (`angle_` is the function's argument, but the two names are confusingly similiar), I guess it's a global variable.

If this is is for on-screen rendering, you might consider limiting yourself to `float` precision and use `sinf()` and `cosf()` instead.